# GoogleMapのマイマップにマーカーを立てるAPIが存在するか？

Tags: google-maps

GoogleMapのマイマップにマーカーを立てようとしています。
経緯度を指定したらマップにマーカーが立つようなAPIは用意されていますでしょうか？
検索しても見つけることができなかったので、質問させていただきました。

ご存知の人がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授願います。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: please use this https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js

Comment: This library seems to be for embedded maps.
Is there anything I can use for my map?

Comment: I am not sure what are u trying. yes it will display iframe with google map. hope it will help u.  https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/53sngk0z/

Comment: I want to put markers on Google My Map via API.
I do not want to prepare static pages.https://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/maps/about/mymaps/